# Pandas `at` vs list `append`

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

I came across a rather puzzling result: pandas `at` assignment is almost 10 times slower than appending a list and converting it to dataframe. Why is this? I understand that pandas `at` deals with a little more complicated structure, but 10 times slower performance seems extreme, rendering thereby clumsy list appending more efficient. I see many posts about slowness of `loc` but `loc` does a lot more than `at` so in a way one can accept its sluggishness.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time

dt = pd.date_range('2010-01-01','2021-01-01', freq='H')
s = pd.Series(data = np.random.randint(0,1000, len(dt)), index = np.random.choice(dt, size=len(dt), replace=False))
d = pd.Series(data = np.nan, index=dt)

t = time.time()
for i in s.iteritems():
    d.at[i[0]] = np.random.randint(10)
print(time.time()-t)

m = []
t = time.time()
for i in s.iteritems():
    m.append((i[0], np.random.randint(10)))
m = pd.DataFrame(m)
m.columns = ['date_time', 'data']
m.set_index('date_time', inplace=True)
print(time.time()-t)
```

output:

```
4.053529500961304
0.3882014751434326
```

Comment: Why does this performance difference puzzle you? Appending to a list isn't clumsy, the entire data structure is optimized for this very operation.

Comment: that `at` has such a bad performance. it should be like a O(1) index lookup in the array.

Comment: `at` is performing a label-based lookup each iteration. Not sure if Pandas uses a hash table but this might be why it is slower than adding an item to the end of a list. Pandas is intended for batch data processing not single values.

Comment: The efficient way to achieve your task with Pandas is: `d[s.index] = np.random.randint(10, size=s.shape[0])`. This is 45 times faster than your list append code.

Comment: B.t.w. are you aware that the output of your list append code (`m`) is not the same as `d`? It is not doing the same task. I think you need to research your question a bit more.

Comment: @guyguyguy12345 why do you think it *isn't* O(1)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pandas` will always lose to a `list` for these sort of simple operations. `pandas` is *written in Python*, and executes a ton of code at the Python interpreter level. In contrast, `list.append`, is written entirely in C. You just have to resolve the method and you are into the C layer.

#### Both operations are Constant Time

Note, *both operations are constant time*, but the constant factors for `pandas.DataFrame.at.__setitem__` are *much higher* than those for `list.append`. Consider the following timings:

```
from timeit import timeit
import pandas as pd, matplotlib.pyplot as plt
setup = """
import pandas as pd

d = pd.Series(float('nan'), index=range({}))

def use_append(s):
    m = []
    for i,v in s.iteritems():
        m.append((i, 42))
    return pd.DataFrame(m)

def use_at(s):
    for i,v in s.iteritems():
        s.at[i] = 42
    return pd.DataFrame(s)
"""
N = range(0, 50_000, 1000)
appends = [timeit("use_append(d)", setup.format(n), number=5) for n in N]
ats = [timeit("use_at(d)", setup.format(n), number=5) for n in N]
pd.DataFrame(dict(appends=appends, ats=ats), index=N).plot()
plt.savefig("list_append-vs-df_at.png")
```

[image]

As you can see, the overall algorithm is linear in both cases.

#### List append Implementation

To reiterate, `list.append` is much faster because it is entirely implemented in C. [Here is the source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/8344fef7dc2cf0ef8a33449df9c165247fb37a3a/Objects/listobject.c#L328)

```
static int
app1(PyListObject *self, PyObject *v)
{
    Py_ssize_t n = PyList_GET_SIZE(self);

    assert (v != NULL);
    if (n == PY_SSIZE_T_MAX) {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_OverflowError,
            "cannot add more objects to list");
        return -1;
    }

    if (list_resize(self, n+1) < 0)
        return -1;

    Py_INCREF(v);
    PyList_SET_ITEM(self, n, v);
    return 0;
}

int
PyList_Append(PyObject *op, PyObject *newitem)
{
    if (PyList_Check(op) && (newitem != NULL))
        return app1((PyListObject *)op, newitem);
    PyErr_BadInternalCall();
    return -1;
}
```

As you can see, there is a wrapper function, and then the main function `app1`, executes the classic dynamic array append, resize internal buffer if necessary, then set the item at the corresponding index of the internal array (see [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/bb3e0c240bc60fe08d332ff5955d54197f79751c/Include/cpython/listobject.h#L33) for the `PyListObject_SET_ITEM` macro definition, which you will see, just sets an array at a given index).

#### Pandas `at` implementation

Alternatively, consider *just a little bit* what happens when you do:

```
some_series.at[key] = value
```

First, `some_series.at` creates a `pandas.core.indexing._AtIndexer` object, then, for that `_AtIndexer` object. [`__setitem__`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/21c299194a2b59a715fa7264bd6b44787deafc7a/pandas/core/indexing.py#L2162) is called:

```
def __setitem__(self, key, value):
    if self.ndim == 2 and not self._axes_are_unique:
        # GH#33041 fall back to .loc
        if not isinstance(key, tuple) or not all(is_scalar(x) for x in key):
            raise ValueError("Invalid call for scalar access (setting)!")

        self.obj.loc[key] = value
        return

    return super().__setitem__(key, value)
```

As we see here, it actually falls back to `loc` if the indices aren't unique. But suppose they are, it then makes an expensive call to `super().__setitem__(key, value)`, taking us to [`_ScalarAccessIndexer.__setitem__`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/21c299194a2b59a715fa7264bd6b44787deafc7a/pandas/core/indexing.py#L2126):

```
def __setitem__(self, key, value):
    if isinstance(key, tuple):
        key = tuple(com.apply_if_callable(x, self.obj) for x in key)
    else:
        # scalar callable may return tuple
        key = com.apply_if_callable(key, self.obj)

    if not isinstance(key, tuple):
        key = _tuplify(self.ndim, key)
    key = list(self._convert_key(key))
    if len(key) != self.ndim:
        raise ValueError("Not enough indexers for scalar access (setting)!")

    self.obj._set_value(*key, value=value, takeable=self._takeable)
```

Here, it handles a special case if the key is a callable (i.e. a function), does some basic bookeeping on the type of the key and checks the length. If all goes well, it delegates to `self.obj._set_value(*key, value=value, takeable=self._takeable)`, yet *another* Python function call. For completion sake, let's look at [`pd.Series._set_value`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/21c299194a2b59a715fa7264bd6b44787deafc7a/pandas/core/series.py#L1152):

```
def _set_value(self, label, value, takeable: bool = False):
    """
    Quickly set single value at passed label.
    If label is not contained, a new object is created with the label
    placed at the end of the result index.
    Parameters
    ----------
    label : object
        Partial indexing with MultiIndex not allowed.
    value : object
        Scalar value.
    takeable : interpret the index as indexers, default False
    """
    if not takeable:
        try:
            loc = self.index.get_loc(label)
        except KeyError:
            # set using a non-recursive method
            self.loc[label] = value
            return
    else:
        loc = label

    self._set_values(loc, value)
```

Again, more book keeping. Note, if we actually were to grow the pandas object, it falls back to `loc`...

```
def _set_values(self, key, value) -> None:
    if isinstance(key, (Index, Series)):
        key = key._values

    self._mgr = self._mgr.setitem(indexer=key, value=value)
    self._maybe_update_cacher()
```

But if the size doesn't change, it finally delegates to the block manager, the internal guts of pandas objects: `self._mgr.setitem(indexer=key, value=value)`... Note this isn't even done yet! But I think you get the idea...

Comment: @guyguyguy12345 note, I updated the answer with some exploration of the different implementations, I think it should be obvious why `list.append` is so much faster, even if they are both technically constant time.

Answer (score 3):

Well... There is no need to use `at` here... Pandas isn't meant to be fast...

The `append` method automatically appends to the end of the list... Where `at` doesn't... Also you're using indexed assignment... Base Python surely would be faster.

The fastest would be bare numpy here:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time

dt = pd.date_range('2010-01-01','2021-01-01', freq='H')
s = pd.Series(data = np.random.randint(0,1000, len(dt)), index = np.random.choice(dt, size=len(dt), replace=False))
d = pd.Series(data = np.nan, index=dt)

t = time.time()
d[:] = np.random.randint(0, 10, len(dt))
print(d)
print(time.time()-t)

m = []
t = time.time()
for i in s.iteritems():
    m.append((i[0], np.random.randint(10)))
m = pd.DataFrame(m)
m.columns = ['date_time', 'load']
m.set_index('date_time', inplace=True)
print(m)
print(time.time()-t)
```

Output:

```
2010-01-01 00:00:00    5
2010-01-01 01:00:00    5
2010-01-01 02:00:00    6
2010-01-01 03:00:00    6
2010-01-01 04:00:00    8
                      ..
2020-12-31 20:00:00    7
2020-12-31 21:00:00    6
2020-12-31 22:00:00    4
2020-12-31 23:00:00    2
2021-01-01 00:00:00    1
Freq: H, Length: 96433, dtype: int32
0.03117227554321289
                     load
date_time                
2018-04-14 04:00:00     6
2014-03-03 23:00:00     2
2010-03-11 20:00:00     1
2017-06-27 16:00:00     2
2020-11-08 11:00:00     6
...                   ...
2016-12-03 08:00:00     9
2020-01-12 16:00:00     5
2014-08-08 10:00:00     5
2012-05-23 04:00:00     8
2010-11-05 06:00:00     2

[96433 rows x 1 columns]
0.4729738235473633
```

As you can see, NumPy is like 10 times faster already for this minor dataset. NumPy is developed some part in C, and it's super quick. Just printed it out to prove that the outputs are the same.

Comment: I don't see the numpy segment of the code.

Comment: @guyguyguy12345 Edited my answer, I miscopied. Now you can see the Numpy